# Class as Hashtable key -- is it a good idea?

Tags: java, class, hashtable

After some consideration, i implemented caching in my application, basically, using a hashtable that contains `Class` as a key (which is the class that corresponds to a particular cached entity and inherits from an abstract `AbstractCache`) and the concrete cache object that is made from that class, which seems quite convenient.

But is it a good idea to have `Class` as a Hashtable key, or should i probably use just the `.canonicalName()` or something like that instead?

Comment: I suspect using `Hashtable` for a cache is not the best choice.  For a cache you usually need to implement your own synchronisation anyway. Otherwise `ConcurrenctHashMap` might be a better choice.

Comment: In addition to Peter's comment: See Google Guava for a Cache implementation that provides concurrency and several other features (optionally weak/soft references, statistics, ...). Even if you don't use it, Guava also has a nice ClassToInstanceMap that will be useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you never need to unload classes, it's probably not an issue. But since requirements may vary based on how your code is run (stand-alone Java app or deployed in web container, enterprise server etc.) it might be wiser not to do this. Classloader leaks are very nasty bugs to track down and solve.

Using the canonical name would seem to be a much better solution. Do keep in mind the other challenge, though: if you have multiple classloaders that might load the same class, those classes will still be considered incompatible. You wouldn't be able to differentiate them by their canonical name, while two identical classes loaded by different classloaders would yield two distinct `Class` instances and could be used as keys in the same map.

If you don't have very specific classloader constraints or requirements, go with the canonical name. If you're deploying as anything else than a stand-alone Java application, be vary wary of the implications.

Comment: I would still use the Class objects. ClassCastExceptions due to incompatible classes are probably worse than classloader leaks, so better be on this side. Additionally, if you store instances of that class as values in that cache, using the canonical name won't help at all for class unloading because you need to remove the entry from the map anyway. If you need this, use Weak/SoftReferences for key and value.

Comment: @PhilippWendler Good advice. I've just remembered that I once needed a class-to-something map and used the `Class` objects rather than names. Provided some method to flush classes from the cache in case unloading was ever needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds fine to me.  I have done this in the past.  Classes are effectively immutable singletons so there's no chance of using the "wrong" instance of a Class.

The only time there would be an issue is if there were multiple ClassLoaders involved but this is rare in most apps.